# Accurately calculating large factorials

Tags: factorial

I need to calculate the exact value of $1,000,000,000!$
It can't be an approximation. As far as I am aware, the only way to do this would be to calculate it starting from the beginning $(1\cdot2\cdot3\cdot\cdots\cdot1,000,000,000)$.

So, I have a program setup to do this, and I improved performance a small amount by grabbing the next 100 numbers, multiplying them together, doing that 100 times, then multiplying them together again, and finally multiplying the result by the running factorial. For example, I am currently at $390,000$. so what the program is doing next is grabbing $390,001$ thru $390,100$ and multiplying those together, repeating this until it reaches $400,000$. At that point it will multiply the numbers from each 100 step together, and multiply that result by the factorial of $390,000$.

So, doing it this way is still way too slow. Is there a better way I could do this?

Comment: I'm curious $-$ why do you need to do this?

Comment: It would probably be faster to wait a couple of hundred years for technology improvements.

Comment: I'm wondering: Does our solar system contain enough energy to actually do this calculation? I honestly have no clue.

Comment: Have a look at the first answer to [this question on the Computer Science StackExcnahge](http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/14456). I don't know whether it's doable, but you will certainly have to use FFT for the multiplications.

Comment: I highly doubt breaking down the order of multiplication should change the computational complexity and hence time taken to solve the problem. The link here may or may not help though https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication_algorithm
also this question will fly better compsci stackexchange

Comment: Also, maybe since the prime factorisation of a factorial is a lot simpler (just take the sum $[\frac{n}{p^k}]$ from $k=1$ to infinity (or n). Where $[x]$ is the floor function for all primes up to $\frac{n}{2}$. This will give you the exponent of the prime factor.) I don't know but maybe it'll make it quicker

Comment: maybe you can find some hints here: http://www.luschny.de/math/factorial/FastFactorialFunctions.htm

Comment: edit: for feasible n! computation, the list of prime numbers up to n is already known and can be reused in computing the function

Comment: What @gebra said. See for example http://www.cut-the-knot.org/blue/LegendresTheorem.shtml

Comment: I can't imagine any possible application where you need this exact value. For numbers this large Stirling's approximation will do a great job

Comment: my bad, it's k from integers one up to logn over logk if you're looking for the minimum

Comment: @MatthewParker One question... what is this for? xD

Comment: I believe that you want to compute this factorial *modulo some other (small) number*, otherwise the funny comments above provide your answer.

Comment: Any good solution around this, Fortunately, working to get the ! for the same number :-) trying couple of  vedic method